# How do you count the number of characters in a string?

Tags: javascript, string

```
var user_name = prompt ("Write your name in the box below","Write it here");
document.write("Hello " + user_name + ". Welcome to my page!");
```

That's my code right now. I want to have it so that once you give your name it will say for example:

> Hello Victoria. Welcome to my page! Your name contains 8 characters.

Comment: Very General question. Didn't conducted any research.

Answer (score 2):

If user for a name enters "Jon Dow" `user_name.length // output 7`
This will be incorrect , because it will count  empty space in between.
To work around this, you could use a help of Regular Expressions!

use instead

```
user_name.replace(/\s/g,"").length;
```

So the resulting code will be :

```
document.write("Hello " + user_name + ". Welcome to my page! Your name contains " + user_name.replace(/\s/g, "").length + " characters.");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
user_name.length
```

All strings have a [length](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/length) property which contains the length of the string. In your code this would look like:

```
document.write("Hello " + user_name + ". Welcome to my page! Your name contains " + user_name.length + " characters.");
```